# How to solve "ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'Item_name' doesn't have a default value"

Tags: mysql

I was working on a MySql project. The table actually has 4 rows.I'm only inserting into one of the rows.

```
insert into items(Item_code) values('X01'),('X02'),('X03'),('X04'),('X05'),('X06'),('X07'),('X08'),('X09'),('X10') on duplicate key update  item_code=values(item_code);
```

I got hit by this error
"ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'Item_name' doesn't have a default value"
Item_name is another column in the same table
pls help me!!

i tried to change it and give the whole column names

```
 insert into items(Item_code,Item_name,Qty,Price) values('X01'),('X02'),('X03'),('X04'),('X05'),('X06'),('X07'),('X08'),('X09'),('X10') on duplicate key update  item_code=values(item_code);
```

when another error shows up
"ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Please someone help me. Also can u make it light because i have just started to use MySQL

Comment: What's the structure of the table?

Comment: "I'm only inserting into one of the rows." - No, you are insering 10 rows. Please read the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Comment: Please execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE items;` and post the result in your question.

Comment: You specify that 4 columns `Item_code,Item_name,Qty,Price` are to be given values for the insert, but you only provide 1 value `'X01'` etc

Comment: You're confusing rows and columns. `Item_code` is the name of a column.